# "No" option not working properly in my Do While loop

Tags: c#, loops, while-loop

So I am fooling around with an RPG-like game using text currently, after going through attacks and counter attacks one time, a dialogue box comes up and asks you if you want to leave but the problem is, "Yes" and No" both causes it to leave the loop, by hitting "No" it's supposed to stay in the loop if your HP and the enemy HP is above 0.  I thought it was working fine until I added code later on in the program but I could be wrong:

```
DialogResult dialogResult;

do
{
    count++;
    if (enemyHP > 0)
    {
        Random rand = new Random();
        int chance = rand.Next(1, 101);

        MessageBox.Show("You see another enemy...);
        MessageBox.Show("Its HP is 10...2/5");
        MessageBox.Show("His current HP is " + enemyHP + ");
        if (chance <= 5)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Miss");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("You dealt 5 damage to it.);
            enemyHP -= 5;
        }

        if (enemyHP > 0)
            MessageBox.Show("He also dealt 5 damage to you.);
        playerHP -= 5;
    }

    if (enemyHP <= 0)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Enemy has been defeated!");
        dialogResult = (0);
    }
    else
     if (playerHP > 0)
    {
        dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Do you want to leave?", "Message box", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
    }
} while (DialogResult == DialogResult.No && enemyHP > 0);
```

Comment: I think this line `} while (DialogResult == DialogResult.No && enemyHP > 0);` has a typo and is the cause of your premature exit. Perhaps the it should be `} while (dialogResult == DialogResult.No && enemyHP > 0);` - note the lowercase 'dialogResult'

Comment: Also `Random rand = new Random();` is going to cause you trouble, initialize it once per application

Comment: @JayV thanks for the answer!  When I changed it there's a red underline and says "use of unassigned local variable"

Comment: @TheGeneral Thanks for the answer! What should I change it to?

Comment: Put it in your main class as a class variable `private static readonly Random _rand = new Random();`

Comment: Btw,I left out some lines of code, running the whole program does work, just the do while loop doesn't (the "No" option doesnt work).

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Thanks for the answer!  In the OP I left out some lines of code, running the whole program does work, just the do while loop doesn't (the "No" option doesnt work).

Comment: @kris change your first line to DialogResult = dialogResult.No to get rid of the red wavy line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in these lines:

1. ```
   DialogResult dialogResult;
   ```
2. ```
   if (playerHP > 0)
   {
       dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Do you want to leave?", "Message box", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
   }
   ```
3. ```
   } while (DialogResult == DialogResult.No && enemyHP > 0);
   ```

As @JayV mentioned, the 3rd line has a typo, it should be:

```
} while (dialogResult == DialogResult.No && enemyHP > 0);
```

However, it can happen that `dialogResult` hasn't been initialized by the time that condition is met, since the assignment happens inside an if branch.
So, modify the first line to provide a default value, which would make sense to be `DialogResult.No`:

```
DialogResult dialogResult = DialogResult.No;
```

---

You also have a little problem here:

```
if (enemyHP > 0)
    MessageBox.Show("He also dealt 5 damage to you.);
playerHP -= 5;
```

The `MessageBox.Show` line runs inside the `if` branch, but since you didn't add brackets, you likely didn't realize that the following line *always* runs.
That's why:

#### Always use brackets!

```
if (enemyHP > 0)
{
    MessageBox.Show("He also dealt 5 damage to you.);
    playerHP -= 5;
}
```

Comment: I am still new to this website so for this comment I will treat someone who posted a "comment" and someone giving an "answer" as two separate things just so I don't confuse anyone!  Thanks to the person who submitted the "answer" it worked!  I can't see your name so Idk who you are haha.  Also thanks to everyone else who posted a "comment"!

Comment: Ok so that worked but now a new problem:  So if you or the enemy aren't defeated yet after hitting "Yes" or "No" you attacked first yet it said "you've been defeated" even though that attack defeated the enemy lol.   It still said you defeated the enemy after it though.  How do I do it so the program knows the enemy has been defeated so the loop ends and the enemy doesn't deal anymore damage to you?

Comment: @Kris I have updated my answer to answer that question

Comment: thanks for the answer but I got it working.  I used "break" within an "if statement" to stop the loop when the condition was met within that "if statement"